# Crank Nicolson MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

Is there any inbuilt solver in MATLAB that solves a given ODE (order>1) using Crank-Nicolson Method? (Note that I have a system of ODE's, so I might solve each one of them using Crank-Nicolson. I tried ode45, but I am not getting correct results)

Comment: I think the closest built-in to Crank-Nicolson would be `ode113` which uses an Adams-Bashforth-Moulton method (CN being equivalent to AM-2).  However, since `ode45` is an adaptive fourth-order method, I wouldn't expect `ode113` to be a huge improvement (especially since both are designed for non-stiff systems).  Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with why you know the solution is wrong?  There may be something else amiss aside from the solver.

Comment: please post a simple, running version of your code.  ODE45 is known to be pretty robust...are you sure you're using ode45 correctly?

Comment: @anon0909 - It's basic Markdown.  The syntax is `[Text here](URL here)`.... so for example [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).  Make sure you add the `http://` identifier, or it won't hyperlink properly.